# How to upload a file automatically without using input file

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, server-side, tmp

I have a flow that uploads a file using `Zend_Form_Element_File` and using an `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` it uploads to the server.

i've modified the flow, and if i already have the file on the server it doesn't show the `Zend_Form_Element_File`. i need to give the file in the server to the `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` but i can't find a way to achieve this

the main problem i have is that the flow uses the `['tmp_name']` of the file (that is obtained with `transfer_adapter`)

creation of form element file:

```
if ($generado==null){
    $element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file'.$i);
    $element->setDestination(UPLOADS_PATH . "/contratistas/");
    // ensure only 1 file
    $element->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
    // limit to 100K
    $element->addValidator('Size', false, 41943040);
    $element->setRequired();
}else{
    //don't create the file element
}
```

Transfer use of the code:

```
 $upload     = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
 $upload->setDestination($sDestino);

 if($generado==null){
     $aArchivos  = $upload->getFileInfo();
 }else{
     $aArchivos = $upload->addFile(array("documento.pdf"));
     error_log("ADD FILE");
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried to use?

Comment: i could but its huge, at least 1000 lines @Technoh

Comment: Can you show us the code that's directly relevant to the question, which means the code where you try to pass the `Zend_Form_Element_File` object to the `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http`?

Comment: @Technoh done. the transfer adapter get the files using `getFileInfo()` which gets an array with all the values i will use next